# .nwd to .obj file conversion failed in Forge

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using Autodesk Forge .Net library to translate a .nwd file to .obj and I am using the below payload to do so.

```
List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>()
                    {
                       new JobPayloadItem(
                         JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Obj,
                         null,
                         new JobObjOutputPayloadAdvanced()
                         {
                             ModelGuid = viewGUID,
                             ObjectIds = new List<int>() {-1}
                         })
                    };
JobPayload job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(ForgeFileURN), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs), new JobPayloadMisc(workflow));
```

but I am getting this error

```
 {
        "name": "LMV Bubble",
        "progress": "0% complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -777",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "obj",
        "status": "inprogress"
    }
```

Any help on how can I solve this problem. After translating this file I want to get metadata properties of that file.

Answer (score 0):

We apologize for the inconvenience had caused. It's a known issue logged as `DERI-7625` by our engineering team. Please take a note of this issue id for future reference. You can check updates via sending an email quoting this issue id to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`.

BTW, could you share your model URN for tacking?

Comment: This is the URN - dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bmV4dmlld3RyYW5zaWVudC9DQ0FfQ29uc3RydWN0aW9uJTIwTWVyZ2VkJTIwQkFTRS5ud2Q. This is a very large file if you can help me with how I can generate Derivative Properties json for this file it will be very helpful. I am not able to generate it from Autodesk .net library or postman or forge vs code extension. It is saying too large (I tried using force download but still it didn't work)

Comment: Could you try with the query string `objectid`?  it will help reduce the generated property JSON size: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/#query-string-parameters

Comment: @Sumana Could you retry the OBJ extraction with `xAdsForce: true`?